# creating dynamic checkbox on runtime

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

```
Dim offset = 200
    For i = 0 To Form1.ListBox2.Items.Count - 1

        Dim cBox = New CheckBox()
        Me.Controls.Add(cBox)
        cBox.Location = New Point(80, offset)
        cBox.Text = Form1.ListBox2.Items.Item(i)
        offset = offset + 50
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Form1.ListBox2.Items.Item(i))

    Next i
```

I'm using this code to create a checkbox during runtime.. problem is how can I put checkChanged event in these checkboxes. looking forward for an answer. ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `AddHandler` command to register an event handler.

```
AddHandler cBox.checkChanged, AddressOf checkChangedHandler
```

Where `checkChangedHandler` is a function like this:

```
Sub checkChangedHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Check Changed")
End Sub
```

Comment: @killd... yes similar code can be used for any `Control` of Windows Forms.

Comment: thank you, please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966527/disabling-dynamic-labels-after-clicking

Comment: i already used and tried your given code.. thank you for that. :) i just use other code because my teacher requested so... I'm sorry for misunderstanding..